# Angular2 PrimeNG, не работает ng-template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2, primefaces

Использую набор компонентов PrimeNG, хочу кастомизировать элемент Tree (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree), использую код

```
<p-tree [value]="companies"
        selectionMode="single"
        [(selection)]="node"
        (onNodeExpand)="onNodeExpand($event)"
        (onNodeSelect)="onNodeSelect($event)">
    <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
        <span>Test: {{node.data}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</p-tree>
```

Никаких ошибок в консоли нет, но и шаблон не применяется, отображается стандартный, как будто блока ng-template нету.

Comment: какую версию primeNG вы используете? спрашиваю потому что в ранних версиях шаблон писался не ng-template а просто template. А документация которую вы приводите в своем вопросе относится исключительно к 4ой версии.